# Get object reference by field name

Tags: java, reflection

```
public class Outer {
    public Inner inner = new Inner();

    public void test() {
        Field[] outerfields = this.getClass().getFields();
        for(Field outerf : outerfields) {
             Field[] innerFields = outerfields[i].getType().getFields();
             for(Field innerf : innerFields) {
                  innerf.set(X, "TEST");
             }
        }
    }

    public class Inner {
        String foo;
    }    
}
```

What should X be? How can I get the referrence of the innerf field (variable inner)?

Comment: @JonK It's just a test sample. But you are right.

Comment: Ok finished editing. Thanks @JonK

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? I mean, at the moment there will be no fields in the arrays you have initialised? Right?

Comment: @Rafik991 There isn't more code. It's just this. Can it be done? If yes then how, if no, why not? Thank you for your response.

Comment: What I want is to know what should I replace X with, in `innerf.set(X, "TEST");` in order to set to variable foo the value "TEST"

Comment: Have deleted my first comment as it's no longer relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get the referrence of the innerf field (variable inner)?

You don't need it. You only need a reference to an object that contains it: in this case, `outerfields[i].get(this).` See the Javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I started this before the other answer was accepted, but here's a complete example:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class Outer
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Outer outer = new Outer();
        outer.test();

        System.out.println("Result: "+outer.inner.foo);
    }

    public Inner inner = new Inner();

    public void test() throws Exception
    {
        Field[] outerFields = this.getClass().getFields();
        for (Field outerField : outerFields)
        {
            Class<?> outerFieldType = outerField.getType();

            if (!outerFieldType.equals(Inner.class))
            {
                // Don't know what to do here
                continue;
            }

            Field[] innerFields = outerFieldType.getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field innerField : innerFields)
            {

                Class<?> innerFieldType = innerField.getType();
                if (!innerFieldType.equals(String.class))
                {
                    // Don't know what to do here
                    continue;
                }

                // This is the "public Inner inner = new Inner()"
                // that we're looking for
                Object outerFieldValue = outerField.get(this);
                innerField.set(outerFieldValue, "TEST");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Inner
    {
        String foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Marco. Although my problem is solved it's very nice to have a complete example for future referrence and testing. Of course upvoted.